# FB Graph API: Separate user by app

Tags: ios, facebook

I have several apps tied to the same Facebook App. The problem is when I try to get all the user friends, then it fetches all friends that have any of the apps installed. How do I filter out and get only the friends that have the active app installed?

In Facebook, the apps are tagged by bundle ID and URL Schema suffix... If I could maybe include any one of those, I could filter the results. Is there a "fields" to include those?

Thanks

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id,name"}] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
       // Filter users by app? 
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a call to `/me/friends` with a User Access Token that belongs to the active App. That´s the only way to get a list of friends who authorized the active App too.

Comment: The problem is, if I call me/friends, I get all the friends that uses the app, but also all the friends that uses the other apps too (tied to the same Facebook app)

Comment: how do you "tie apps together"? that´s not really possible. or do you mean the business mapping api?

Comment: tie maybe is the wrong word, but I have a paid and a LITE version for example.

Comment: what does that have to do with tying apps together? what access token are you using? a user token created through the active app? because that´s what you need.